# Convert dict with tuples to json

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following input:

```
input =  {'foo': [('aaa', 'bbb'), ('ccc', 'ddd')], 'buz': [('xxx', 'yyy')], 'bar': [[]]})
```

I want to convert it to something like:

```
"name": "foo"
    "values": [
     {    
        "first":"aaa", 
        "last":"bbb"
     },
     { "first": "ccc",
       "last":"ddd
     }
    ],
"name": "buz"
    "values": [
     {    
        "first":"xxx", 
        "last":"yyy"
     }],
"name" : "bar
"values":[]
```

I tried doing something like :

```
[{'name': k, 'values': [(v1, v2)]} for k, [v1, v2] in input.items()]
```

But getting this error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I think it is due to the fact that in some cases the values list is empty

Comment: Usually you can just use the `json` module to serialize your `dict`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Your desired result isn't value JSON. You can't use the same keys in the same object, you need an array of objects.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa They want to reorganize it first.

Comment: You're unpacking the value of all dict items as `[v1, v2]`, but there's not always two of them. But as @JanChristophTerasa said: why do this yourself and not use standard libraries?

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa I guess you mean something like `json.dumps(res)` yes, i did try that but that will give me something like `"buz":[["xxx","yyy"]]` which is not what i'm looking for

Comment: @prune the question is more about reorganizing a dict than dumping it to JSON.

Comment: Ah, my bad, sorry.

Comment: I don't understand why the downvote @JanChristophTerasa

Comment: Not my downvote and perhaps not theirs either; but if your question's title doesn't match its contents, and the contents don't properly explain how the expected output can be derived from the example input, someone might downvote (or even flag to close as "needs details or clarity") just for that. This should be easy to fix with a quick [edit], and improve your chances of getting adequate answers to your actual question.

Comment: @tripleee i tried to update the headline to something more accurate , if you have any other suggestions please share, thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify what you are trying to do. If this is not about creating a JSON, do not ask about creating a JSON. If you want some specific output, please do not request "something like" malformed JSON/Python and show "something like" code doing something else – *clearly* define what you expect and what you have tried *to achieve this*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need nested list comprehensions:

```
input_data =  {'foo': [('aaa', 'bbb'), ('ccc', 'ddd')], 'buz': [('xxx', 'yyy')], 'bar': [[]]}

[{
    "name": key, 
    "values": [
        {"first": v[0], "last": v[1]} for v in value if v
    ]}
 for key, value in input_data.items()]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got ` for first, last in value
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)` i think that this because sometimes the value is empty

Comment: `foo` and `buz` values are a list of 2-element tuples. Why is `bar` a list with an empty list?

Comment: BTW, don't use `input` as a variable name, it replaces the `input()` function.

Comment: I fixed it and tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Smth like this:

```
from functools import partial

keys = ("first", "last")
data = {"foo": [("aaa", "bbb"), ("ccc", "ddd")],
        "buz": [("xxx", "yyy")],
        "bar": [[]]}

print([{"name": key,
        "values": [dict(i) for i in map(partial(zip, keys), filter(None, value))]}
       for key, value in data.items()])
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'foo', 'values': [{'first': 'aaa', 'last': 'bbb'}, {'first': 'ccc', 'last': 'ddd'}]}, {'name': 'buz', 'values': [{'first': 'xxx', 'last': 'yyy'}]}, {'name': 'bar', 'values': []}]
```

Comment: thanks, maybe i am missing something, but i want to use specific names to the attributes and not a simple numeration

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that the value should be consider as single value:

```
[{
    "name": key, 
    "values": [
        {"first": names[0], "last": names[1]} for names in value if names
    ] 
 for key, value in input.items() ]
```